# Read JSON Data failed after modify the object name

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON file. I want to read the value of tags after modify the tag name like example:

JSON:

```
{"T1": 5, "T2": 1, T3: 15}
```

and I use callback function to parse the data as:

```
GetFieldData('ReadData', updateFields);
```

and:

```
function updateFields(data){ 
    console.log("T2 = " + data.T2);
}
```

I get `T2 = 1`

So far it is OK but when I try to use the code below:

```
function updateFields(data){ 
    i = 2;       
    var myVar = ("T" + i);
    console.log("myVar = " + data.myVar);    
}
```

I got

```
T2 = undefined
```

What is going wrong and why I am getting undefined?

Comment: The output "T2 = undefined" can not come from `updateFields`, you should clarify

Answer (score 1):

There's no `myVar` member in your object.

If you want the member whose *name* is contained in `myVar`, say:

```
function updateFields(data){ 
  i = 2;       
  var myVar = "T" + i;
  console.log(myVar + " = " + data[myVar]);    
}
```

```js
function updateFields(data) {
  i = 2;
  var myVar = "T" + i;
  console.log(myVar + " = " + data[myVar]);
}

var o = {
  "T1": 5,
  "T2": 1,
  T3: 15
};

updateFields(o);
```

Comment: I was just to answer this question and you come with solution, thump up.